# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA77369138 (ScriptHookV.dll) in GTA5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. occurred

Tags: windows, dll, windows-10, access-violation

When I have dsound.dll in Rockstar GTA5 game directory, and then launch GTAVLauncher.exe using a fork of RenderDoc ( https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data ) I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA77369138 (ScriptHookV.dll) in GTA5.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. occurred
```

When I launch the game using renderdoc but disable the dsound.dll like dsound.dll_disabled this error doesn't happen. I need dsound.dll for script hook v. Here's what I see when I try to debug the crash with Visual Studio:
[image]

Additionally, this is the output from the debug:

```
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GFSDK_ShadowLib.win64.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\dsound.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\bink2w64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfplat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msdmo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfreadwrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\D3DCompiler_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GFSDK_TXAA_AlphaResolve.win64.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput8.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\xinput1_3.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\D3DX9_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dsound.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\RTWorkQ.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Release\renderdoc.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.14393.447_none_0d5aa7fbb6d35646\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\openexr\lib\IlmImf.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\ilmbase\lib\Half.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\ilmbase\lib\Iex.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\ilmbase\lib\Imath.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\ilmbase\lib\IlmThread.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\zlib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Release\pdblocate\x64\dbghelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Release\pdblocate\x64\symsrv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\LUA.asi'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\ScriptHookV.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3dx11_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\NativeTrainer.asi'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\OpenIV.asi'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\ScriptHookVDotNet.asi'. Module was built without symbols.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvspcap64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvapi64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10_1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10_1core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvStereoApiI64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvSCPAPI64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvgbwu.inf_amd64_ad333ca77156045c\nvwgf2umx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\XAudio2_7.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AudioSes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptnet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Social Club\socialclub.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\pid.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FirewallAPI.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fwbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fwpolicyiomgr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wdmaud.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'GTA5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x3dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[13124] GTA5.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here's the report from my DirectX diagnostic tool:
https://pastebin.com/LVR6mtu6
Here's the report from msinfo32:
https://pastebin.com/hqZ0Uzxc

ScriptHookV.log:

```
// GTA V SCRIPT HOOK (build Mar 17 2017, v1.0.1011.1)
//     (C) Alexander Blade 2015-2017
[15:02:41] INIT: Started
[15:02:41] INIT: Success, game version is VER_1_0_1011_1_NOSTEAM
[15:02:41] INIT: Registering script 'LUA.asi' (0x00007FFA6E06E6A0)
[15:02:42] INIT: Registering script 'NativeTrainer.asi' (0x00007FFA99C2A3C0)
[15:02:43] INIT: Registering script 'ScriptHookVDotNet.asi' (0x00007FFA8E9214A0)
[15:03:49] INIT: Pool 1 extended
[15:03:49] INIT: Pool 2 extended
[15:03:49] INIT: Pool 3 extended
[15:03:49] INIT: Pool 4 extended
[15:03:54] INIT: GtaThread collection size 188
[15:03:54] INIT: wnd proc 0x00000000FFFF0839
[15:03:54] INIT: IDXGISwapChain 0x00007FFA7AEBEB48 (0x00007FFA7AD41950)
[15:03:54] INIT: IDXGISwapChain set
```

asiloader.log:

```
000
001
// GTA V ASI LOADER (build May  2 2015)
//     (C) Alexander Blade 2015
LIB: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsound.dll" => 00007FFA723C0000
API: "DirectSoundCreate" => 00007FFA723E94F0
API: "DirectSoundEnumerateA" => 00007FFA723E95F0
API: "DirectSoundEnumerateW" => 00007FFA723CC540
API: "DllCanUnloadNow" => 00007FFA723F2BB0
API: "DllGetClassObject" => 00007FFA723CB840
API: "DirectSoundCaptureCreate" => 00007FFA723E92C0
API: "DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateA" => 00007FFA723E94D0
API: "DirectSoundCaptureEnumerateW" => 00007FFA723CF9F0
API: "GetDeviceID" => 00007FFA723C98A0
API: "DirectSoundFullDuplexCreate" => 00007FFA723E9610
API: "DirectSoundCreate8" => 00007FFA723CC5A0
API: "DirectSoundCaptureCreate8" => 00007FFA723E93C0
002
LOADER: Loading *.asi plugins
ASI: Loading "C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\LUA.asi"
     "LUA.asi" => 00007FFA6E040000
ASI: Loading "C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\NativeTrainer.asi"
     "NativeTrainer.asi" => 00007FFA99C20000
ASI: Loading "C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\OpenIV.asi"
     "OpenIV.asi" => 00007FFA97EB0000
ASI: Loading "C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\ScriptHookVDotNet.asi"
     "ScriptHookVDotNet.asi" => 00007FFA8E920000
LOADER: Finished loading *.asi plugins
```

Here's the screenshot of files and folders I have in GTAV game directory:
[image]

and here's renderdoc diagnostic report:

```
RENDERDOC:  [15:01:26]             core.cpp( 242) - Log     - RenderDoc v0.27 x64 (NO_GIT_COMMIT_HASH_DEFINED) loaded in replay application
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:02]    win32_process.cpp( 307) - Log     - Injecting renderdoc into process 3392
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:02]    remote_access.cpp( 389) - Log     - Got remote handshake: GTAVLauncher () [3392]
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:09]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 10080 38921
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:18]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 3740 38923
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:18]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 4492 38923
RENDERDOC:  [15:02:32]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 13124 38923
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:18]    win32_network.cpp( 169) - Warning - recv: 10054
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:21]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38920
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:24]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38920
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:27]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38921
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:30]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38921
RENDERDOC:  [15:08:33]    win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38921
```

Additionally, these are the options I have selected for launching the game using renderdoc:
[image]
More details from msinfo32 report:

```
     3/30/2017 9:08 PM   Application Error   Faulting application name: GTA5.exe, version: 1.0.1011.1,
time stamp: 0x58be92cc&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting module name: ScriptHookV.dll,
 version: 1.0.1011.1, time stamp: 0x58cbb2b9&#x000d;&#x000a;Exception code:
 0xc0000005&#x000d;&#x000a;Fault offset: 
0x0000000000009138&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting process id:
 0x3344&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting application start time: 
0x01d2a998f2b24669&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting application path:
 C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe
&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting module path:
 C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\ScriptHookV.dll
&#x000d;&#x000a;Report Id: 4e4e10d7-2167-42ba-b4b6-616643c300c7&#x000d;&#x000a;
Faulting package full name: 
&#x000d;&#x000a;Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I really don't know what exactly causes the problem as well as how to fix this. If further information is need, please comment and I will add them.

Comment: You need to debug ScriptHookV.dll.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate the causes, as I suspect this error is irrelevant to Renderdoc. Launch GTALauncher.exe directly not from renderdoc, and see whether the game crashes.

ScriptHookV is a mod framework on top of ASI Loader, and is loaded with ScriptHookV.asi. ASI Loader is a more low-level mod framework, and is loaded with `dinput8.dll` or `dsound.dll` (It just uses these directx file names for GTA to automatically load them). `dinput8.dll` and `dsound.dll` corresponds to different versions of ASI loader and different versions of ScriptHookV also depend on the correct version of ASI loader. More info at http://www.dev-c.com/gtav/scripthookv/ .

I suggest you to download the correct version of ScriptHookV/ASI loader from the website above and replace them with all files now in GTA directory, including `dsound.dll, dinput8.dll, *.asi, ScriptHookV.dll, ScriptHookVDotNet.dll, etc.`

Comment: The game doesn't crash when I only run the game having script hook v stuff in the folder. The problem happens when I launch the game from that specific fork of renderdoc and also have script hook v in the directory. And yes, I do need to use that specific fork.

Comment: I have done what you said and have downloaded the latest versions of them and it didn't work. I have been working with these libraries for more than 5 months so I know their details to a good extent.

Comment: how about hooking into GTA with global hook rather than "child process" hook?